# Add exception in .htacces rule

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using this rule in .htaccess to redirect requests to a subdirectory, say 'images', and anything inside it:

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/images/.*$
```

However, the problem is that requests from my own domain are blocked too, so there are no images displayed on the site.

So I would like to insert an exception, for mydomain.com.
Any hints appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted is broken, can u post the full code that you tried and failed?

Comment: I'm using just this code... I didn't know it's broken.
Anyway, the purpose is to redirect requests for any data inside a sub-directory, EXCEPT from my own domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add exception to your domain with RedirectMatch directive.

You need mod_rewrite here

```
 RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/.*$ - [R=403,L]
```

The rule will return 403 forbidden error for /images except "domain.com".

Replace domain.com with yourdomain.com

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using RewriteEngine, but it seems it's not possible...
Anyway, thanks.